# Can I execute multiple statements in SQL Server Compact 4?

Tags: sql-server-ce-toolbox

I'm trying to get multiple inserts to work in a single script using the SQL Compact 4.0 Toolbox and not having any luck.  I keep getting a parsing error.

I've even tried adding GO; between each statement like so..

```
INSERT INTO ... ;

GO;

INSERT INTO ... ;
```

with no luck.. so am I out of luck? Do I have to just execute each statement one at a time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Update to the latest release version (2.3). There was a bug with multiple statement execution, that has been fixed in the latest release version.
Seperate each statement with GO on a separate line, no semicolon after...
Like the INSERT statements created by the tool:

```
INSERT INTO [Shippers] ([Shipper ID],[Company Name]) VALUES (1,N'Speedy Express');
GO
INSERT INTO [Shippers] ([Shipper ID],[Company Name]) VALUES (2,N'United Package');
GO
INSERT INTO [Shippers] ([Shipper ID],[Company Name]) VALUES (3,N'Federal Shipping');
GO
```

Comment: Are you talking about the stand alone version or the addin?  There is a 2.3 for addin and all I can find is 2.1.0.6 for the stand alone?

Comment: Updated answer, as I noticed a semicolon after your GO statement

Comment: So I have 2.1.0.6 installed AND 2.3 add in installed and after removing the semi colons everything worked great.